# Asked by previous company to help them freelance in a project

Tags: professionalism, freelancing, work-time, projects

I have had very good relations with my previous organization . A result of it , that the HR called up and asked them to help them out with estimations and working on this new project . I was the only developer on that particular technology there (Yea , you guessed it right . It was ROR ) . As this is an exciting opportunity , but at the same time it's quite confusing for me .

Given the fact , that i have left the company . How will i communicate for asking resources (designs and also api related development for mobile technologies) . As i see things , i will be able able to work only after my office hours (at which time , their's get over too) . I am really in a fix here as i have started the proceedings and the project looks sure to land , looking for some helpful suggestions here or someone who has been in a similar spot .

Comment: Related - [What to do when previous boss is asking to help finishing failed project?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31617/what-to-do-when-previous-boss-is-asking-to-help-finishing-failed-project?rq=1)

Comment: My case is a bit different  , I will be getting paid here .

Comment: You lose a day but ask for a contact and use email.

Comment: @CaffeineCoder - Yes, it is different enough that it's worth a separate question, but there still might be some useful information in some of the answers.

Comment: I've done this before; in my contract I made it clear I would be unavailable during my FTE hours and in the event of a conflict of interest my FTE would always win out.  If your former employer isn't willing to accept those terms, then walk way.  Its not worth jeopardizing your FTE for moonlighting.  Also be sure to discuss with your FTE as well.

Comment: Question of a different sort...are you employed by a different company in the same field? If so, there might be conflict of interest involved that could land you in serious troubles.

Answer (score 3):

This is not unlike having a team that works across incompatible time zones. While it may take longer, is email out of the question? You can draft your questions in the evening and they respond the following day.

The other option when you really need to communicate during the day is to take time off from the other job.

Do be careful about conflict of interest issues though. To protect yourself from your present employer it could be necessary to get a waiver from them that this work will not be considered their work product.